# Special variables in ggplot (..count.., ..density.., etc.)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following lines.

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=..count..))

p + geom_histogram()   
p + stat_summary(fun.y=identity, geom='bar')
```

In theory, the last two should produce the same plot. In practice, `stat_summary` fails and complains that the required y aesthetic is missing.

Why can't I use `..count..` in `stat_summary`? I can't find anywhere in the docs information about how to use these variables.

Comment: Those variables are returned by `stat_bin` which is called by `geom_histogram`, but not by `stat_summary` (since you're supposed to be supplying your own stat), hence the variables aren't available.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Expanding @joran's comment, the special variables in ggplot with double periods around them (`..count..`, `..density..`, etc.) are returned by a stat transformation of the original data set. Those particular ones are returned by `stat_bin` which is implicitly called by `geom_histogram` (note in the documentation that the default value of the `stat` argument is `"bin"`). Your second example calls a different stat function which does not create a variable named `..count..`. You can get the same graph with

```
p + geom_bar(stat="bin")
```

In newer versions of `ggplot2`, one can also use the `stat` function instead of the enclosing `..`, so `aes(y = ..count..)` becomes `aes(y = stat(count))`.

Comment: I'd like to perform an arithmetic operation (in this case, addition) between `..count..` variable and a user-defined variable (I've done it with constants). Unfortunately, `ggplot2` doesn't recognize the variable's name and produces an error. Any ideas, Brian?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh That should be a new question, not a comment to the answer of an old question. Offhand, I don't think it is possible. A variable in your primary data.frame would have more values than the transformed `..count..` variable, so there would be no way to match them up. Without more detail and a reproducible example (e.g. a new question), I can't answer for sure, though.

Comment: Fair enough! I thought that this question is too "small" and not worth a separate posting. I've already figured that it's not possible, your comment additionally confirms that. Thank you!

Comment: I really wish geom_bar generated the ..density.. variable like its cousin function geom_histogram does.

Answer (score 2):

As [part of ggplot 3.3.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3534), the preferred API has changed to use the `after_stat()` method. The following are equivalent:

```
aes(y=..count..)
aes(y=stat(count))
aes(y=after_stat(count))
```

With the release of v3.4.0, the former two have been deprecated, and `after_stat()` is the preferred API (see [Release Notes](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.4.0)).

There is [documentation explaining the evaluation staging](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html), but knowing what computed values are available depends on the particular layer being added. For example, the `stat_bin()` layer (which `geom_histogram()` uses) will compute:

- `count`
- `density`
- `ncount`
- `ndensity`
- `width`

This info can be found in [the *"Computed variables"* section](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html#computed-variables) of the method documentation. Another example is `stat_count()` (which `geom_bar()` on discrete uses) computing `count` and `prop` (see [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html#computed-variables)). So, consult the particular layer for similar info.