# Two points operator in ggplot2 examples

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the ggplot2 examples, one finds a lot of code with two points used around parameters.
For instance, in the `stat_density` documentation:

```
m <- ggplot(movies, aes(x=rating, weight=votes/sum(votes)))
m + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..)) + geom_density(fill=NA, colour="black")
```

What does `..something..` mean? How can it be used? Is there any mention of it in the documentation? I am having trouble finding any reference to this due to the difficult *searchability* of `..`

Comment: See also a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14570293/892313

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`something` is a new variable that has been produced by a *stat*, which is a `ggplot2` mechanism that will transform your original dataset in some way (e.g., binning the data, smoothing the data). The `..` distinguishes it from variables in your input, so that there's no confusion.

In your example, `..density..` is the density, which you can map the height of the histogram bars to, rather than the raw count in each bin (`..count..`, the default). `..density..` is computed by `stat_bin`.

As far as I know, there's no one place in the documentation where this is explained (though if you have access to the `ggplot2` book, look at section 4.7), but the new variables created by each stat are listed in the stat documentation pages, under the Value section. For example, looking at the [documentation for stat_bin](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_bin.html), you can see that the variables `count`, `density`, `ncount`, and `ndensity` are created, which can be accessed by `..count..`, `..density..`, `..ncount..`, and `..ndensity..`.

Comment: Thanks for that complimentary info, now I understand.