# Display frequency instead of count with geom_bar() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

On [this page](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/), they give the following example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
ggplot(data=tips, aes(x=day)) + geom_bar(stat="bin")
```

Instead of a count I'd like to have a frequency in y-axis. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here's the solution which can be found in [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/ggplot-showing-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables):

```
pp <- ggplot(data=tips, aes(x=day)) + 
      geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))
```

If you would like to label frequencies as percentage, add this (see [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_continuous.html)):

```
library(scales)
pp + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the dot-dot notation in `..count..`? Do you have any reference to that?

Comment: @mcrisc Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc).

Comment: How would you obtain data labels for the frequencies, to be shown above each bar?

Comment: I really wish `geom_bar` generated the `..density..` variable like its cousin function `geom_histogram` does.

Comment: I think think `labels=percent` in `scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)` doesnt work anymore

Comment: @dieHellste Running on `ggplot2_3.1.0`, `scales_1.0.0` is still fine (R 3.5.1, Win 10).

Answer (score 23):

now `..prop..` is available

```
ggplot(data=tips, aes(x=day)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., group = 1))
```

Comment: This works if you are using facets, while the `..count..` option does not!

Comment: @r_alanb do you mean adding e.g. `facet_wrap(~sex)`? It works with both for me.

Comment: I should have defined "works". It will create a figure if you use `..count../sum(..count..)`, but the frequency will sum to 1 over all of the facets (I think). If you use `..prop..`, the frequency will sum to 1 in each facet. Maybe it depends on what you're trying to show.

Comment: @r_alanb `..count../sum(..count..)` and `..prop` work exactly the same for me as long as you set `group = 1`

Comment: `ggplot(data=tips, aes(x=day)) + geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., group = 1)) + facet_wrap(~sex)` and `ggplot(data=tips, aes(x=day)) + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), group = 1)) + facet_wrap(~sex)` do not yield the same plot for me. You can also remove `group=1` in the `..count..` version and it looks  the same.

Answer (score 1):

With ggplot2 >= 3.4.0, I think the recommended way is the following:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

ggplot(data = tips, aes(x = day)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(prop), group = 1))
```