# Frequency density barplot of categorical variable

Tags: r, bar-chart, frequency

I'd like to plot a barplot of frequency density of the following ordered categorical data:

```
summary(ACC[EA$TYPE=="A"])
NG SG LG MG HG 
 2 25 36 17  0
```

If I plot:

```
plot(ACC[EA$TYPE=="A"])
```

I get:

[image]

But I'd like to divide all the values by the total to get a frequency density:
Ie.
`plot(ACC[EA$TYPE=="A"]/sum(as.numeric(ACC[EA$TYPE=="A"])))` but that doesn't work. Any tips?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default plotting function for a `factor` is `barplot`. So if you want a different graph, it may be easier to directly use this function: (with a random factor example)

```
f <- factor(sample(letters[1:5], 100, r=T))
h <- table(f) / length(f)
barplot(h)
```

[image]

Getting the [same result with `ggplot2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835987/display-frequency-instead-of-count-with-geom-bar-in-ggplot) is trickier, and for some reason, I needed to put the data in a `data.frame` for it to work:

```
dat <- data.frame(f = f)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=f, y=..count.. / sum(..count..), fill=f)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: if you have a factor, that's a better option indeed!

Comment: Thank you for this, it works like a charm. This way I don't even have to rename the xticks. What does putting f into a table do though? Yes f is a factor.

Comment: ggplot2 only likes `data.frame`s, and if (`ggplot()` is) passed with something else, it will be `fortify`ied on the fly.

Comment: How would you add data labels above each bar?

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to fix it with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610), so I created one for you. The following works like a charm:

```
# creates the vector
x <- c(2, 25, 36, 17,  0)
names(x) <-  c("NG", "SG", "LG", "MG", "HG") 

# raw x = counts
barplot(x, ylab="Count")
# when divided by the total count, we obtain frequencies and we barplot them
barplot(x/sum(x), ylab="Frequency")
```

I see no reason why this could not work as long as `ACC[EA$TYPE=="A"]` is a numeric:

```
barplot(ACC[EA$TYPE=="A"]/sum(ACC[EA$TYPE=="A"]), ylab="Frequency")
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I appreciate your help. In particular thank you for putting the link to a reproducible example. I know I need to do this but never know how.