# Create data labels for frequency plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495155/frequency-density-barplot-of-categorical-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, a frequency figure can be created using ggplot. For example:

```
f <- factor(sample(letters[1:5], 100, r=T))
h <- table(f) / length(f)
dat <- data.frame(f = f)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=f, y=..count.. / sum(..count..), fill=f)) + geom_bar()
```

How do I now obtain data labels for each individual bar within the figure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `geom_text()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=f, y=..count.. / sum(..count..), fill=f)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label=..count../100))
```

[image]