# What does the ".." refer to in ggplot's "fill=..density.."?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working my way through The R Graphics Cookbook and ran into this set of code:

```
library(gcookbook)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) + 
   geom_point() +
   stat_density2d(aes(alpha=..density.., fill=..density..), geom="tile", contour=FALSE)
```

It runs fine, but I don't understand what the `..` before and after `density` is referring to. I can't seem to find it mentioned in the book either.

Comment: `..density..`, `..count..` and others refer to variables that have been created on-the-fly by ggtplo2 using a stat_xxx function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc

Answer (score 6):

Variable names beginning with `..` are possible in R, and are treated in the same way as any other variable.  Trying creating one of your own.

```
..x.. <- 1:5
```

`ggplot2` often creates appends extra columns to your data frame in order to draw the plot.  (In `ggplot2` terminology, this is "fortifying the data".)  `ggplot2` uses the naming convention `..something..` for these fortified columns.

This is partly because using `..something..` is unlikely to clash with existing variables in your dataset.  Take that as a hint that you shouldn't name the columns in your dataset using that pattern.

The `stat_density*` functions use `..density..` to represent the density of the x variable.  Other fortified variable names include `..count..`.

Comment: I thin instead that is more of a flag to choose a variable named "density" in a local data.frame created by `?stat_bin`. One can even use the variables `density` or `counts`, but attempts to use a variable named `..density..` would fail.

Comment: @DWin I've completely rewritten the answer so that it is no longer garbled nonsense.

Comment: Except according to the ?stat_bin page (and my limited experience),  the actual names are `density` , `count`, `ncount` and `ndensity`. I do agree that the choice of the spelling for the "fortification" flag was to avoid collision with user names.