# Maintaining a scale of a histogram when using ..ncount

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, histogram, label

Using the code below, I'm generating a set of simple histogram:

```
data(mtcars); Vectorize(require)(package = c("ggplot2", "ggthemes", "dplyr"))
mtcars %>% 
    add_rownames(var = "model") %>% 
    gather(var, value, -model, -am) %>% 
    filter(var %in% c("hp")) %>% 
    # Define chart
    ggplot(aes(value)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..ncount..), colour = "black", fill = "gray58",
                   binwidth = 15) +
    geom_density(aes(y = ..scaled..), colour = "red") +
    facet_wrap( ~am, ncol = 3, scales = "free")
```

[image: First attempt]

I would like to maintain scale that is produced when generating a histogram without the `..ncount..` special variable, as in the example:

```
mtcars %>% 
    add_rownames(var = "model") %>% 
    gather(var, value, -model, -am) %>% 
    filter(var %in% c("hp")) %>% 
    # Define chart
    ggplot(aes(value)) +
    geom_histogram(colour = "black", fill = "gray58",
                   binwidth = 15) +
    geom_density(aes(y = ..scaled..), colour = "red") +
    facet_wrap( ~am, ncol = 3, scales = "free")
```

[image: poor geom_density]

But it makes the `geom_density` look poor.

## Task

So what I want boils down to:

- keep scale of `y` axis from the second one
- keep graphics from the first one

Comment: @SandyMuspratt I had a look at the linked post. I don't know how to achieve the final outcome where I can take scale from the *second* chart and graphs from *first* one. With respect to the graphs, I'm satisfied with the first chart but I want scale from the second.

Comment: My vote goes for calling `hist` in advance, and then `scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:nmax/nmax, labels = 0:nmax)`.

Comment: @tonytonov I will have a look, thanks for the suggestion. I understand that you also suggest to leave `y = ..ncount..` for the `geom_hist`?

Comment: Yes, either that or (even better) `geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")` on the precomputed histogram, so you won't do the same thing twice.

Comment: OK, I will play with it. Following [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14570974/1655567) I reckon that it would be actually useful to access a special variable pertaining to the value *before* transformation.