# Plot distribution using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with the language R to generate average samples follow a normal distribution. The distribution of the variable `X` is not showing in the chart. I am getting a blank chart in my R plots. I used the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
d = data.frame(X=rbeta(20000,2,5))
p = ggplot(d, aes(x=X))
p + geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) + ylab("Frequency Percent")
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `geom_histogram` for continuous data:

```
?geom_histogram
```

> Display a 1d distribution by dividing into bins and counting the
>   number of observations in each bin.
>   ...

```
R> p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=X))
R> p + geom_histogram(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
   ylab("Frequency Percent")
```

[image: plot]

`geom_histogram` uses `stat_bin` by default, which bins data in ranges and counts the cases in each range. It differs from `stat_count` (default stat for `geom_bar`), which counts the number of cases at each `x` position (without binning into ranges). `stat_bin` requires continuous `x` data, whereas `stat_count` can be used for both discrete and continuous `x` data.

Comment: `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.

Comment: e.g. `geom_histogram(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth=0.025)`

Comment: See `?stat_bin`: By default, `stat_bin` uses 30 bins - this is not a good default, but the idea is to get you experimenting with different binwidths. You may need to look at a few to uncover the full story behind your data.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `stat = "bin"`

```
set.seed(1)
d = data.frame(X=rbeta(2000,2,5))
p = ggplot(d,aes(x=X))
p + geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat="bin") +
    ylab("Frequency Percent")
```

[This SO answer is helpful here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570974/4272484)

Comment: stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth

Comment: Is this a question or an observation?

Comment: In another set of plot distribution i used stat="bin", but showing some Warning message:
Removed 5035 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).

Comment: Check for `NA`s, `NaN`s and +/-`Inf`s in your data, `geom_bar` and `geom_histogram` remove those for counting purposes.