# How can I use a variable in aes() with ..count.. in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do this

```
library(ggplot2)

foo <- 4
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = ..count.. + foo)) + geom_histogram()
```

And I'm getting

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'foo' not found
```

Oddly, this works

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt + foo)) + geom_histogram()
```

Why is it that I can add foo to wt in aes(), but not to ..count..?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc) thread