# Referring to special variable in ggplot when adjusting scale of a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, scoping

## Background

I'm looking at a possibility of using [**special variables**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc) *`(..count.., etc.)`* while adjusting elements of a histogram.

## Example

For instance the code below generates a simple histogram with the bars stretched to the maximum length of the panel and the neat margin ot the top achieved through `limits = c(0,15)`.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = cyl)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,15))
```

#### *Preview*

[image: Initial histogram]

### Problem

My intention is to make the `limits = c(0,15)` dynamic and connect to the maximum available count *without the necessaity to generate a separate data frame*. Consequtntly, I would like to make use of the special variables, for example, I would like to add **10%** margin on top with use of the code:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = cyl)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0, ..count.. * 1.1))
```

however, this results in an error:

```
Error in continuous_scale(c("y", "ymin", "ymax", "yend", "yintercept",  : 
  object '..count..' not found
```

I understand that `..count..` should be available as it's created by `stat_bin` called by histogram, as per [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570974/1655567).

Comment: Are you opposed to using `limits = c(0, max(table(mtcars$cyl)) * 1.1))`?

Comment: Or, as an alternative to `..count.. <- max(table(mtcars$cyl))`, sth like `ggplot(mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(x = cyl)) -> p; p + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, max(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$count) * 2.1))`.

Comment: @Zach Thanks for showing the interest, if push comes to shove I could live with this but here I want to make use of the `..count..` partially because I never use those things partially because the actual shart is part of a longis dplyr manipulation and actual data frame would be more complex than `table(mtcars$cyl)`, in practice `..count..` would solve it.

Comment: `..count..` is only available within the `geom_histogram` aesthetics (in this case). It is not available anywhere else (as far as I know) including other geoms and stats, scales etc. One possible reason is that one can easily add multiple geoms that use `stat_count`, and it is unclear to which count `..count..` should refer.

Comment: @Axeman Thanks very much for that input, this is useful and informative. Your explanation makes sense, shame that there is no way to fish it out, `geom_histogram()$..count..` but that would be comparable to solution that *Zach* and *lukeA* offered.

Comment: @Konrad; Yes, fishing it out would involve `ggplot_build` as lukeA shows.

Comment: The only truly neat solution to this actual problem would be that ggplot starts supporting unsymmetrical `expand` arguments somehow. But that seems unlikely.

Comment: @Axeman If you wish to collate your comments in an answer I would be happy to accept as it closes the discussion.