# How to filter ggplot bar graph to only show counts above a threshold

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I use the following to produce the bar graph below.  How would I only visualize bars where the count is above, say, 20?  I'm able to do this kind of filtering with the which function on variables I create or that exist in my data, but I'm not sure how to access/filter the auto-counts generated by ggplot.  Thanks.

```
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
g + geom_bar()
```

[Simple bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWu3g.png)

Comment: Not sure how to do this, I agree with MSR below that the easy solution is just to aggregate the data beforehand. However, as we can see with geom_text, it should be possible to access the count to throw it on a filter
`ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) +  geom_bar() + geom_text(stat = 'count', aes(label=..count..))`

Answer (score 2):

Aggregating and filtering your data before plotting and using `stat = "identity"` is probably the easiest solution, e.g.:

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% 
  group_by(class) %>%
  count %>%
  filter(n > 20) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, so the auto-counts are ..count.. in aes (yes I know it's weird, you can see [Special variables in ggplot (..count.., ..density.., etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc)). And if you apply an ifelse, that makes it NA if < 20, then you have your plot.. (not very nice code..)

```
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
g + geom_bar(aes(y = ifelse(..count.. > 20, ..count.., NA)))
```