# How to produce an inverse cumulative histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am able to produce a cumulative histogram as below. Using mtcars as an example, each car has a certain number of carburetors. For each quantity of carburetors (x axis), the plot shows the number of cars with **less than** that many carburetors. I would like to produce a plot which shows the number of cars with **greater than** that many carburetors.

[This link provides further explanation](https://peterstatistics.com/Ultimate/Session2/S02E05/S02E05-2-InvCuFreq/S02E05-2-InvCumFreq.html)

Thanks!

```
mtcars %>% 
ggplot(aes(carb)) +
geom_histogram(aes(y = cumsum(..count..)))
```

[image: Displayed plot]

Comment: That is not a histogram, it is just a column/bar chart.  If you provide some sample data, I sure someone can provide a suggest on where to start.

Comment: I think you want `stat_ecdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat_ecdf()` is a good starting point for this visualization but there are a few modifications we need to make.

1. In a CDF, `y` represents the probability density of values **less than** a given value of `x`. Since you're looking for the density of values **greater than** `x`, we can instead invert the output. For this we make use of the special internal variables computed by `ggplot()`. These used to be accessed through `..` or `stat()` nomenclature (e.g. `..y..` or `stat(y)`). Now the preferred nomenclature is [`after_stat()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html) (also described in [this](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#more-control-over-aesthetic-evaluation) and [this](https://yjunechoe.github.io/posts/2022-03-10-ggplot2-delayed-aes-1/) blog posts). So the final code specifies this inversion inside the `aes()` of `stat_ecdf()` by setting `y = 1 - after_stat(y)` meaning, "once you've calculated the y value with the `stat`, subtract that value from 1 before returning for plotting".
2. You want to see actual count rather than probability density. For this, one easy option is to use a [second axis](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html) where you specify this transformation by simply multiplying by the number of observations. To facilitate this I calculate this value outside of the `ggplot()` call because it's cumbersome to access this value within `ggplot`.
3. Since you are asking for a value of `y` that is the count of observations with a value **greater than or equal to** `x`, we need to shift the default output of `stat_ecdf()`. Here, I do this by simply specifying `aes(carb + 1)`. I show both versions below for comparison.

Note: I'm showing the points with the line to help illustrate the actual `y` value at each `x` since the `geom = "step"` (the default `geom` of `stat_ecdf()`) somewhat obscures it.

```r
library(tidyverse)

n <- nrow(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(carb)) +
  stat_ecdf(aes(y = (1 - after_stat(y))), geom = "point") +
  stat_ecdf(aes(y = (1 - after_stat(y))), geom = "step") +
  scale_y_continuous("Density", position = "right",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(name = "Count", trans = ~.x*n)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), breaks = 0:8) +
  ggtitle("y = count with carb > x")
```

[image]

```r
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(carb + 1)) +
  stat_ecdf(aes(y = (1 - after_stat(y))), geom = "point") +
  stat_ecdf(aes(y = (1 - after_stat(y))), geom = "step") +
  scale_y_continuous("Density", position = "right",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(name = "Count", trans = ~.x*n)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, NA), breaks = 0:9) +
  ggtitle("y = count with carb >= x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was after. Can you please suggest what to edit to produce a plot such that the `y` value at any given `x` represents the number of observations **greater than or equal to** that value of `x`? Sorry if this is a very simple modification - tbh I'm not really sure what `..y..` means here and can't find much online. Do you know where I can read about this?

Comment: If you want "greater than or equal to" you probably need to shift all the values because `stat_ecdf` calculates just what's less than the value. The `..y..` is a kind of weird syntax. It refers to special variables that are internally computed by `ggplot` which you can still access and use. I don't know if there's formal documentation on it but it's described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc) post.

Comment: I found an important mistake in the original answer. I have updated with a better version and more explanation of the `..y..` business.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars |> 
      select(disp) |>
      ggplot(aes(disp, y = 1 - ..y..)) +
      stat_ecdf()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I think this is close but I'm trying to produce a plot where the y axis shows a cumulative count rather than a density. Also, ideally would like to show this using a histogram but if not possible then this would work as well!

Comment: FYI - no need to `select` just the variable you want to plot. That's what `aes()` is for.